# Django Authentication - Created CustomUser and now I can't login anymore

Tags: python, django, authentication

I've put together a custom user model to store a few new fields and to keep the DB/UI models separate.  I can create the user fine from a python shell and validate the password:

```
>python manage.py shell -c "
     from itemdb.models import MyUser;
     user = MyUser.objects.create_user('mypass','AD','Joe','Smith','1233','joe@smith.com');
     print user.check_password('mypass');
 "
 True
```

But when I point my app to the new "MyUser" model, I can't login via the web form anymore:

> Please enter a correct userid and password. Note that both fields may
>   be case-sensitive.

I created a new "users" table with the required fields and the hashed password values are being stored in the "password" field.

I've written a few functions that may override the default functions, like "get", "save" etc.  I'm guessing the issue is in there somewhere.  My other guess, is somehow the form is not passing the right credentials.

I know the easiest and cleanest way is to extend the model -- I've read all the posts & tutorials.  But I want to keep the DB & UI code separate as much as possible.  I think I'm close.  What's missing?  Any ideas as to why the validation isn't working via the website?

Postgres 9.6
Python 2.7
Django 1.11

**urls.py** (truncated)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name= 'itemdb'

urlpatterns = [

    # Authentication/Admin
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page':'/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^passwordreset/$', auth_views.logout, name='passwordreset'),

    # Index (i.e. /itemdb/)
    url(r'^$', views.itemindex, name="itemindex"),

]
```

**login.html**

```
{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'itemdb.MyUser' # Point to custom user model
...
```

**Users table DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    UserType CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(25),
    EmailAddress VARCHAR(250),
    Password VARCHAR(128),
    Last_Login TIMESTAMPTZ,
    PRIMARY KEY(UserId)
);
```

**SP_IGLGetUser**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION $DB_NAME$Views.SP_IGLGetUser(
    pUserId INTEGER
)
RETURNS SETOF $DB_NAME$Views.Users
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT UserId, UserType, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, Password, Last_Login
    FROM $DB_NAME$Views.Users
    WHERE (UserId = pUserId OR pUserId IS NULL) -- Return single user (if specified, otherwise return all)
    ;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

**models.py** (truncated)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from UsefulFunctions.dbUtils import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Data model managers (i.e. interface between DB and objects)
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    # Create new user
    def create_user(self, password, usertype = None, firstname = None, lastname = None, phonenumber = None, emailaddress = None):
        user = self.model(
            userid=None,
            usertype=usertype,
            firstname=firstname,
            lastname=lastname,
            phonenumber=phonenumber,
            emailaddress=self.normalize_email(emailaddress)
        )

        # Save hashed password
        user.set_password(password)

        # Save user data and update user object with newly created id
        result = user.save()
        user.userid = result[0]

        return user

    def get_all(self):
        users = getDBData(self, 'SP_IGLGetUser(%s)', (None,))

        # Return list of user objects
        return users

    # Get info for one specific user
    def get(self, userid):
        user = getDBData(self, 'SP_IGLGetUser(%s)', (userid,))
        return user[0] # First and only row of array

    def upsertUser(self, myUser):
        return saveDBData('SP_IGLUpsertUser', 
            (
                myUser.userid,
                myUser.usertype,
                myUser.firstname,
                myUser.lastname,
                myUser.phonenumber,
                myUser.emailaddress,
                myUser.password,
                myUser.last_login,
                None
            )
         )

    def deleteUser(self, myUser):
        return deleteDBData('SP_IGLDeleteUser', (myUser.userid, None))

# Data models (i.e. tables)
# Create custom base user
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    # Define attributes (inherited class includes password + last_login fields)
    userid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # Specify as PK to prevent Django from creating "id" column and for queryset returns (raw)
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    emailaddress = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    # Define data manager
    objects = MyUserManager()

    # Create new constructor (must be passed in correct order)
    def __init__(self, password = None, last_login = None, userid = None, usertype = None, firstname = None, lastname = None, phonenumber = None, emailaddress = None):

        # Call parent's init function
        super(get_user_model(), self).__init__()

        # Set properties
        self.userid = userid
        self.usertype = usertype
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.phonenumber = phonenumber
        self.emailaddress = emailaddress
        self.last_login = last_login

    # Class info
    class Meta:
        managed = False # Ensure Django doesn't "manage" the table
        db_table = 'users' # Point to actual DB table

    # Required fields
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'userid' # specify how Django recognizes the user
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'emailaddress'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['usertype','firstname','lastname'] # email and password are required by default

    # Required methods
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname + " (" + self.userid + ")"

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.userid

    def save(self):
        return MyUser.objects.upsertUser(self)

    def delete(self):
        return MyUser.objects.deleteUser(self)
```

**dbUtils.py**

```
from django.db import connection
from collections import namedtuple

# Return all rows from a cursor as named tuples (i.e. rows with field names)
def namedtuplefetchall(cursor):
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    nt_result = namedtuple('Result', columns)

    return [
        nt_result(*row) 
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

def getDBData(myobjects, sp_signature, params):
    objectlist = []

    # Execute raw SQL on object manager and return RawQuerySet object
    objects = myobjects.raw('select * from ' + sp_signature, params)

    # Convert RawQuerySet to list of model instances    
    for myobject in objects:
        objectlist.append(myobject)

    return objectlist

def getRawDBData (sp_name, param_list):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:        
        cursor.callproc(sp_name, param_list)
        return_data = namedtuplefetchall(cursor) # Create "rows"
        cursor.close()

    return return_data

def saveDBData(sp_name, param_list):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:        
        cursor.callproc(sp_name, param_list)
        return_data = cursor.fetchone() # Store any output
        cursor.close()

    return return_data

def deleteDBData(sp_name, param_list):
    return saveDBData(sp_name, param_list)
```

**Update**
It looks like the problem is related to get_by_natural_key, which is returning an empty value for the password field.  My test call:

```
>python manage.py shell -c "
   from itemdb.models import MyUser;
   user = MyUser.objects.create_user('mypass','AD','c','k','123','email');
   print user.userid, user.password;
   print user.check_password('mypass'); 

   newuser = get_by_natural_key(user.userid)
   print newuser.check_password('mypass')
   print newuser.firstname, newuser.password, newuser.emailaddress
 "
>94 <password_hash_string>
>True
>False
>c  email
```

The create_user() call stores and validates the password fine.

Then I try to re-retrieve the newly created user with get_by_natural_key(user.userid).  This call creates a MyUser object with all the values populated, except for the "password" field.

I called the underlying DB function directly and it does in fact return the "password" field with the hashed value.

I've made some progress, but this is where I'm stuck.  I can't see why it's not passing the "password" value to the new object.  Any ideas?

**Data flow**

```
get_by_natural_key  
  objects.get()  
    getDBData()  
      objects.raw()  
        SP_IGLGetUser() --> Postgres function call
```

Comment: What does `MyUser.objects.get_by_natural_key(your_user_id). check_password('your_password')` output?

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction.  
  
MyUser.objects.get_by_natural_key(93).check_password('mypass') returns **False**  
Please see my latest comment and let me know what you think...

Comment: Does `MyUser.objects.get_by_natural_key(93) == MyUser.objects.get(userid=93)`? What does `django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password(your_user.password, 'actual_password')` return? I would add some breakpoints into `django/contrib/auth/base_user.py` and see where stuff starts getting weird.

Comment: `MyUser.objects.get_by_natural_key(93) == MyUser.objects.get(userid=93)`  

True  

`myuser = MyUser.objects.get_by_natural_key(93);  
print hashers.check_password(myuser.password,'mypass')`  
  
False  
  
`user=MyUser.objects.get(userid=105);  
print hashers.check_password(user.password,'mypass')`  

False

Comment: Not sure what's going on...I'll give it a go with the breakpoints.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: It seems to me like your custom database functions aren't actually correctly inserting the data into your database. Can you verify if the user's password is actually set to something by using your database's command line? In your first example, `user.check_password('mypass')` evaluates to `True`. That user object's fields weren't populated from your database, they were assigned in your object's initializer. What happens if you fetch `user = MyUser.objects.get(userid=123456)` and then try `user.check_password('mypass')`?

Comment: Yes, the user.save() function calls the upsertSP and the password hashes are being stored in the DB:  

`SELECT PASSWORD FROM sp_iglgetuser(93);  

> pbkdf2_sha256$36000$A16eHD59mEeD$IxarnQRosrO/8rGqKk7yyNjzK3E1PF3qt+zNTBO/UpA=`  

I think the sticking point is getting the "password" field back from the SP in the objects.get() calls and populating it into the MyUser objects.  
.  
``user=MyUser.objects.get(userid=93);  
print user.check_password('mypass')`  
> False

Comment: Is `user.password` populated when you retrieve the user from the database? Your database retrieval functions kinda defeat the whole purpose of using Django's ORM.

Comment: Yes, when I call the database SP/function, it returns the password hash.  
But like you see above, the user class "get" functions return all the fields populated, except for password.  And yes, I know :)  I just want to have the DB calls separate.  Gimme some time to keep playing with this and I'll post an update.  Maybe it's a reserved keyword with Postgres...there's a few things I still need to try.

Comment: It's official...I'm a dummy :)  In my constructor for the MyUser class, I was allowing for the "password" field, but not setting it.  Nice.  I'm starting to see how painful this can be, so I may give Django some more control, we'll see.  Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Ah, that would do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot set a password from `.created` function, you have to use:

```
a = User(username='your_username', email='..', ..)
a.set_password('your_pass') # then you use this for create the password
```

The reason is that Django has to hash the password so we use that function

Comment: Thanks, I checked this part and it seems to be working ok.